# Hide buttons in WPF usercontrol from WPF application window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

In a WPF application, i use a WPF usercontrol where the buttons are in.

For the applictaion, i want to make a simple and an advanced version, so some buttons in the usercontrol should be shown/hidden when in the WPF application a checkbox is set to simple or advanced mode.

I do not want to put the checkbox directly in the usercontrol, as it is multiple times on the WPF application.

So my question basically is:
How can i set the state of buttons in the WPF usercontrol from out of the WPF application?

Comment: Have a button visible property in the user control.  If are going to bind it to the checkbox then I think it will need to be a depedancy property.

Answer (score 0):

If using MVVM you could have a base ViewModel expose a boolean IsAdvancedMode (which you'd set accordingly) and then make use of the BooleanToVisibilityConverter ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx)) in the buttons UserControl.